# How to add a class to a bar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

How to add a class to the bar when the user hover on the bar ?
I deployed a code like the one below, but didn't get the proper output.

For example in CSS, we add code like ".bar:hover:before", in the same manner how can I add the .bar:hover:before in jQuery ?

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bars li .bar").each(function(key, bar) {
    var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

    $(this).css('height', percentage + '%');

    $(this).animate({
      'height': percentage + '%'
    }, 1000);
  });
});


$(window).load(function() {
  $('.bar').prepend('class="lnr lnr-star"');

})
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 650px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: block;
}
#chart #numbers {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#chart #numbers li {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  height: 29px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
}
#chart #numbers li:last-child {
  height: 30px;
}
#chart #numbers li span {
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
#chart #bars {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #444;
}
#chart #bars li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#chart #bars li .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: #49E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
#chart #bars li .bar:hover {
  background: #5AE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#chart #bars li .bar:hover:before {
  color: white;
  content: "\e814" attr(data-percentage);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}
#chart #bars li span {
  color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2em;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.lnr.lnr-star {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="chart">

  <ul id="bars">
    <li>
      <div data-percentage="56" class="bar"></div><span><i class="lnr lnr-star"></i></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to append class on hover anchor link ?

Comment: I added the code, David Thomas
and Sorav Garg, yes I want to add hover and before both the '.bar' class in jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, you would use the [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) method. So what you would do instead of prepending it. You would do this: `$('.bar').addClass('lnr lnr-star');` Prepending items doesn't add it inside the tag, it puts it as another item before the object selected. When calling a function when the user hovers over an object, you would use the [.hover()](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) method. With the HTML, you already have the icon, you can remove its classes since jQuery will add the classes to the icon. So all together you would have:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#bars li .bar").each(function(key, bar) {
    var percentage = $(this).data('percentage');

    $(this).css('height', percentage + '%');

    $(this).animate({
      'height': percentage + '%'
    }, 1000);
  });
});


$('.bar').hover(function() {
  $('.bar-icon').addClass('lnr lnr-star');
}, function() {
  $('.bar-icon').removeClass('lnr lnr-star');
});
```

```css
#chart {
  width: 650px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  display: block;
}
#chart #numbers {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
#chart #numbers li {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  height: 29px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
}
#chart #numbers li:last-child {
  height: 30px;
}
#chart #numbers li span {
  color: #eee;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
#chart #bars {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #444;
}
#chart #bars li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
#chart #bars li .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: #49E;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
#chart #bars li .bar:hover {
  background: #5AE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#chart #bars li .bar:hover:before {
  color: white;
  content: "\e814" attr(data-percentage);
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}
#chart #bars li span {
  color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2em;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.lnr.lnr-star {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.linearicons.com/free/1.0.0/icon-font.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart">

  <ul id="bars">
    <li>
      <div data-percentage="56" class="bar">
        <i></i> 
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can I add like this ` $('.bar:hover:before').addClass('lnr lnr-star'); ` in jQuery ? @qxest

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Sorry but no, '.bar:hover:before' is CSS not jQuery. Look at the current code, is this what you were asking?

Comment: nope, it is not working :( @qxest -
I want like this <div data-percentage="56" class="bar" style="height: 56%;">::before</div>, at before I want that class

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain, ::before cannot be targeted by jQuery, you would have to use spans and divs.